# Word Quiz - How to properly implement VIEW and HTML page Django

Tags: django

I am building a website for learning vocabulary in English. The website let users add words in English and an association on how to remember the word in Hebrew.
I want to add a word quiz function.
The user gets 4 random words from the database and has to choose the right word and if he answered correctly he gets the right answer I get a little tricky how to implement it and would be happy to help.

What do I do wrong when I click on a word I get nothing? (I try to get the "message")

```
def practice(request):
    words_list = Words.objects.filter(approved= True)  # Take all the words that approved by the admin
    random_word_to_guess = random.choice(words_list) # Take one random words from the DB
    word_1 = random.choice(words_list)
    word_2 = random.choice(words_list)
    word_3 = random.choice(words_list)
    if request.method == "POST":
        quiz = request.POST.get("quiz") #Grab the search item
        if quiz == 'correct': # if the user click on button that his name =correct - the choice is correct
            message = "Correct answer"
            return render(request, "practice.html", {'message': message})
        else:
            message = "Wrong answer"
            return render(request, "practice.html", {'message': message })

    return render(request, "practice.html", {'word_1':word_1,'word_2':word_2,'word_3':word_3,'random_word_to_guess':random_word_to_guess,})
```

HTML PAGE

```
<h1> Practice </h1>
    </br>
    {{random_word_to_guess.English_word}}
</br> </br> </br>

<form name = "guess" action ="" method="post" class="from-inline">
    <button name = "uncorrect" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{word_1.Hebrew_word}}</button>
    <button name = "uncorrect" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{word_2.Hebrew_word}}</button>
    <button name = "uncorrect" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{word_3.Hebrew_word}}</button>
    <button name = "correct" type="button" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{random_word_to_guess.Hebrew_word}}</button>

    {{message}}
<strike>
</form>
```

URL:

```
    path("practice",views.practice, name = "practice"),
```

Comment: Can you please tell what do you want to do with this line? `if request.POST.get("correct"):`
Do you get the information whether it is correct or wrong from the form?

Comment: Ok I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you do the official django tutorial to understand how it works because this code shows a fundamental misunderstanding of how these things work.

If you don't learn these things, you'll be asking questions non stop and that's no good for anyone. Take the hour or so to complete the official Django tutorial and you will understand how to do this.

Comment: I tried search on the internet how to Identify which submit button was clicked .. I'll be happy if you can just help me with the view I try to find the solution long time I edited my code .. If you just take a look more one time

Comment: @YoavLavie On your form you have `action=""` either remove that or add the url for your view.